# Custom teams application opening in browser by default (Teams Mobile)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a custom teams app. In the Desktop Teams, everything works great.
In the Mobile Teams (Android & IOS), the application opens by default in the browser (it's a tab app). But if i open the context menu and click "Open", everything works great...

Is it possible to set the "default open mode", or disable the "Open in browser"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To open app tab in teams client the `WebsiteUrl` in must have value. For more details please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs#mobile-considerations).